# Skipping overlapping labels on x-axis for a barchart in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

How do I skip labels on x axis in dc.js chart dynamically, so that they should not overlap for large dataset.

[image]

Here is part of my script

```
 requestDateBarChart
            .width(725)
            .height(300)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 60, left: 30})
            .dimension(requestDateDimension)
            .group(requestDateGroup)
            .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(coh.map(function (d) {return d.customerRequestDate; })))
            .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
            .elasticY(true)
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .on('renderlet',function(chart){
                  chart.selectAll("g.x text")
                    .attr('dx', '-15')
                    .attr('transform', "rotate(-55)");
                })
            .controlsUseVisibility(true);
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but adding vague extra tags like "javascript" and "charts" never helps with dc.js questions, and can sometimes even attract unwanted attention (haters). I've added the d3.js tag because it is relevant for axis questions - see below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The axes in dc.js are produced by d3.js, so there's a huge community out there to help with this one. To access the x Axis you can use `chart.xAxis()` - just be careful because this returns an axis object, so [I don't recommend chaining it with your other chart initialization code](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis).

In this case, I searched for "d3 axis ordinal ticks" and [this example popped up](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3212294). The relevant function is [`axis.tickValues()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues).

Since you're using `coh.map(function (d) {return d.customerRequestDate; })` to produce the x scale domain, you could use every 4th tick like so:

```
var domain = coh.map(function (d) {return d.customerRequestDate; });
requestDateBarChart.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(domain))
var ticks = domain.filter(function(v, i) { return i % 4 === 0; });
requestDateBarChart.xAxis().tickValues(ticks);
```

If you figure out some maximum number of ticks `MAXTICKS` that can fit in the space, you could maybe do:

```
var stride = Math.ceil(domain.length / MAXTICKS);
var ticks = domain.filter(function(v, i) { return i % stride === 0; });
```